# Coverage PHPT tests in PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit, phpdbg

Run simple PHPT test

```
--FILE--
<?php
  var_dump(1);
?>
--EXPECT--
int(1)
```

by PHPUnit command with phpdbg. But I've got the error

TypeError: Return value of PHPUnit\Runner\PhptTestCase::cleanupForCoverage() must be of the type array, boolean returned in /home/anastasia/foundation-packages/visualxmleditor/trunk/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/PhptTestCase.php:547

PHPUnit version  => 7.1.5
PHP Version => 7.1.16

Comment: are you using a framework?

Comment: StackOverflow is not an issue. Please report bugs on GitHub, thanks.